# PSexec is not starting to machine using supplied username and password

Tags: pstools

Hi i am trying to connect windows 7 enterprise to windows server 2008 Enterprise R2
but it fails to start the service and stuck. without prompting any error like access denied etc..

I have administrator rights to windows server 2008.

your help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory can you ping it, can you rdp to it?  I believe psexec uses the IPC$ share so you may want to check that it hasn't been removed from the server.

On the Windows 7, shift-click on cmd.exe and run-as different user then enter your admin credentials then run "psexec \server cmd" from here.  I'm suggesting this just to verify you're logged in with admin creds and the cmd prompt on the remote server is easy to verify with commands like "hostname" or "whoami".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes i can ping and rdp to it. but still stuck at prompt Starting PSexec on <server-ip-address> ....